# C: memory error by using realloc

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

Considering the toy-code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH (5000)

typedef struct request_body_s {
    char *data;
    size_t size;    // in bytes
} request_body_t;

int do_something(request_body_t *request_body) {
    char* content = read_content_elsewhere("/dir/content");
    size_t size = strlen(content) * sizeof(char);
    request_body->data = (char *) realloc(request_body->data, size + 1);
    if (request_body->data == NULL)
        return 0;
    else {
        request_body->size = size;
        strncpy(request_body->data, content, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    request_body_t request_body;
    request_body.data = malloc(1);
    request_body.size = 0;

    if (do_something(&request_body))
        printf("Read!\n");
    else {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    free(request_body.data);
    request_body.size = 0;
}
```

This code seems work fine until `free(request_body.data)` is called; it generates an error as follows:

```
*** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001594570 ***
```

What is (of course) wrong and why? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried freeing the entire `request_body`?

Comment: Your example program is missing certain parts, and also contains other errors. Please prepare a minimal, working example.

Comment: You know that you may pass a null pointer to `realloc()`, in other words your first call to `malloc()` is not needed.

Comment: `man strncpy(): [...]If  the  length of src is less than n, strncpy() writes additional null bytes to dest to ensure that a total of n bytes are written.[...]`.

Comment: You should try using a debugger like valgrind in future. If you pass (the fixed version of) your code to valgrind it correctly notes that the error is on line 19 (`strncpy(...)`). Its a very useful tool for c development!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is right here:

```
 strncpy(request_body->data, content, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

depending on your goal (not clear from your description), I would suggest:

```
strncpy(request_body->data, content, size > MAX_STRING_LENGTH ? MAX_STRING_LENGTH : size );
```

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy` copies the first n chars of the string, that is 5000 in your case. If the source string is smaller that `n` (5000 here), the rest is padded with zeros, therefore you are accessing further that the end of your bufffer, which leads to undefined behaviour.

You need:

```
strcpy(request_body->data, content);
```

It is safe here to use `strcpy` because we can be sure that the memory allocated by `realloc` is large enough, because you `realloc` `strlen(content) + 1` chars.

BTW `* sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, so the `* sizeof(char)` is not necessary.

Comment: `request_body->data` has already been sized specifically for `content`, so using `strcpy` instead of `strncpy` is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [strncpy manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy),

> If the length of src is less than n, strncpy() writes additional null bytes to dest to ensure that a total of n bytes are written.

So, by using `strncpy(request_body->data, content, 5000);`, you write many '\0' outside your buffer. You **shouldn't ever do that**, it's an undefined behaviour, and, in this case, you're writing on the 'metadata' used by `free`, so it crashes.

Here, it would be preferable to use `strcpy` (and make sure to add a '\0' at the end), or `memcpy`, because you know the size you want to write.

Also, [casting the return of malloc is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and sizeof(char) is and will very probably always be 1, so it's also useless.